# How do I write logs in file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, httplib

I am using httplib in my python code and have following mentioned.

`import httplib
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 2`

I do get all the info I need but httplib library is printing it on console.

I do not know any way by which I can get all those logs in a log file and not on console.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the httplib source (https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/httplib.py) you'll see the debugging is done via print statements, so you can't use logging configuration to intercept the logs, and because print is a statement, you can't monkeypatch it to do your bidding.

You have a few options:

1. Use an alternative to httplib
2. Subclass HTTPConnection and do something ugly with `__getattribute__` (or just write pass-throughs for every method you want to log) and log when calls happen.
3. Depending on what you're doing, just redirect your program's stdout into a file.

Comment: I want to redirect my program's stdout but how can I do it till the program execution finishes? Do you have any other recommendation for alternative of httplib for logs? I am using requests to send a request but it I havent found anything for logging in it.

Comment: `$ python yourscript.py > logfile` writes the stdout of your script to a file called logfile. If you want to see the output _and_ write it to a file, `$ python yourscript.py | tee logfile`. Requests uses standard library logging. It's documented as part of upgrade notes at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/ (search "logging")

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
f = open('output.txt','w')
sys.stdout = f
```

Redirecting stdout to a file.

Comment: Writing it to a file can work but can we somehow write till the program execution is not complete. What could be the condition for that?